# loop through a files in docs

Tags: batch-file, dos

i have a file that goes like this:

```
10.4.33.22 ocean,cat,dog,monkey
33.55.66.77 rabbit,piggy
```

i created a for loop to loop through the IP address.

```
for /F %%i in (%File_dbname%) do ( 
   echo %%i database >> %output-file%
)
```

there are 4 instances in the first IP address.

I was thinking of using another for loop to loop through those instances/ per IP address.

I am not sure how to use any delimiter, to skip the spaces between the 1st IP address and go to ocean until it hit monkey and when detected the spaces after monkey it will go to the next line.

Please further advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest for loops the way you describe.  Here's an example:

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in (%File_dbname%) do ( 
    for %%A in (%%j) do (
        echo %%i %%A >> %output-file%
    )
)
```

Using the example data you mentioned, the result would be:

```
10.4.33.22 ocean 
10.4.33.22 cat 
10.4.33.22 dog 
10.4.33.22 monkey 
33.55.66.77 rabbit 
33.55.66.77 piggy
```

Is that what you're looking for, or does it at least let you see how it works?

In a `for` loop without any `/f` switch or similar, a comma is treated as a delimeter.  In the `for /f` loop, `"tokens=1*"` means `%%i` is the first token (meaning everything up to the space), while `%%j` is everything not included in `%%i`.

Comment: Rojo, your example have helped to understand further. Is it still possible by not having to repeat the entry of the same IP address?

Comment: Of course.  Just `echo %%i database >> %output-file%` outside the inner loop, then within the inner loop `echo %%A >> wherever you want`.

Comment: Rojo.Tks for the pointer. Will you be able to recommend me some sites for beginners?

Comment: some sites can be confusing and put me off. Will be good to have explanations like yours with code example.

Comment: @flaskvacuum - [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/) is a good reference.  I'm probably not a good person to ask about sites for beginners, though, as I've been messing with DOS and Windows batch scripting for going on three decades now.